# Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to ... must be an instance of ..., array given

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine, entity

I want to register a user. In my database I have a table `user` with a FK `player_id` and in my players table I have a FK `team_id` from my team table.

This is my RegisterType Form:

```
class RegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('userFirstname', 'text', [
                'label' => 'Given name*',
                'attr'  => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Enter your given name.',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('userSurname', 'text', [
                'label' => 'Family name*',
                'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'Enter your family name.'],
            ])
            ->add('userType', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array('E' => 'ENTHOUSIAST', 'P' => 'PLAYER', 'T' => 'TRAINER'),
                'label'   => 'User Type*',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'User Type')
            ))
            ->add('player', new PlayerType())
            ->add('userUsername', 'text', [
                'label' => 'Username*',
                'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'Enter a username.'],
            ])
            ->add('userEmail', 'email', [
                'label' => 'Email address*',
                'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'Enter your email address.'],
            ])
            ->add('userPassword', 'repeated', [
                'type'           => 'password',
                'first_name'     => 'password',
                'first_options'  => [
                    'label' => 'Password*',
                    'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'Enter a password.'],
                ],
                'second_name'    => 'confirm',
                'second_options' => [
                    'label' => 'Password (repeat)*',
                    'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'Repeat the password.'],
                ],
                'invalid_message' => 'The passwords are not identical.',
            ])
            ->add('btn_register', 'submit', [
                'label' => 'Register',
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'register';
    }
}
```

As you can see I've added a link to another form 'PlayerType'. This is my PlayerType Form:

```
class PlayerType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('playerLicensenumber', 'text', [
                'label' => 'Your License number*',
                'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'Enter your license number.'],
            ])
            ->add('playerPosition', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array('T' => 'Trainer', 'S' => 'Spelverdeler', 'R' => 'Receptie/Hoek', 'L' => 'Libero', 'M' => 'Midden', 'O' => 'Opposite', 'A' => 'All-round'),
                'label'         => 'Position you play at*',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Enter your play position.')
            ))
            ->add('playerBirthyear', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Your Birth Year',
                'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'Enter your birth year.'],
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('team', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'You play with*',
                'attr'  => ['placeholder' => 'Enter your team.']
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'player';
    }
}
```

And in my register.html.twig view I have all my user fields an my player fields like this:

```
<div class="form-group{{ registerForm.player.playerLicensenumber.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
    {{ form_label(registerForm.player.playerLicensenumber, label|default(),
    { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        {{ form_widget(registerForm.player.playerLicensenumber,
        {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
    </div>
    {% if not registerForm.player.playerLicensenumber.vars.valid %}
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 has-error">
            <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
            {{ form_errors(registerForm.player.playerLicensenumber) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
<div class="form-group{{ registerForm.player.playerBirthyear.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
    {{ form_label(registerForm.player.playerBirthyear, label|default(),
    { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        {{ form_widget(registerForm.player.playerBirthyear,
        {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
    </div>
    {% if not registerForm.player.playerBirthyear.vars.valid %}
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 has-error">
            <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
            {{ form_errors(registerForm.player.playerBirthyear) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
<div class="form-group{{ registerForm.player.playerPosition.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
    {{ form_label(registerForm.player.playerPosition, label|default(),
    { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        {{ form_widget(registerForm.player.playerPosition,
        {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
    </div>
    {% if not registerForm.player.playerPosition.vars.valid %}
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 has-error">
            <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
            {{ form_errors(registerForm.player.playerPosition) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
<div class="form-group{{ registerForm.player.team.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
    {{ form_label(registerForm.player.team, label|default(),
    { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        {{ form_widget(registerForm.player.team,
        {"attr": {"class": "form-control"} }) }}
    </div>
    {% if not registerForm.player.team.vars.valid %}
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 has-error">
            <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
            {{ form_errors(registerForm.player.team) }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

This is my Users Entity Class:

```
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_username", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userUsername;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_firstname", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userFirstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_surname", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userSurname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userEmail;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_type", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $userType;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_password", type="string", length=60, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userPassword;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_salt", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userSalt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_token", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $userToken;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_created", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $userCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_modified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userModified;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userDeleted;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_lastlogin", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userLastlogin;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_confirmed", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userConfirmed;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_locked", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userLocked;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="role_id")
     * })
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_follows_teams",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="team_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $team;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_follows_competitions",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="competition_id", referencedColumnName="competition_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $competition;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->team = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->competition = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Set userUsername
     *
     * @param string $userUsername
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserUsername($userUsername)
    {
        $this->userUsername = $userUsername;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userUsername
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserUsername()
    {
        return $this->userUsername;
    }

    /**
     * Set userFirstname
     *
     * @param string $userFirstname
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserFirstname($userFirstname)
    {
        $this->userFirstname = $userFirstname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userFirstname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserFirstname()
    {
        return $this->userFirstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set userSurname
     *
     * @param string $userSurname
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserSurname($userSurname)
    {
        $this->userSurname = $userSurname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userSurname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserSurname()
    {
        return $this->userSurname;
    }

    /**
     * Set userEmail
     *
     * @param string $userEmail
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserEmail($userEmail)
    {
        $this->userEmail = $userEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userEmail
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserEmail()
    {
        return $this->userEmail;
    }

    /**
     * Set userType
     *
     * @param string $userType
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserType($userType)
    {
        $this->userType = $userType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userType
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserType()
    {
        return $this->userType;
    }

    /**
     * Set userPassword
     *
     * @param string $userPassword
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserPassword($userPassword)
    {
        $this->userPassword = $userPassword;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userPassword
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserPassword()
    {
        return $this->userPassword;
    }

    /**
     * Set userSalt
     *
     * @param string $userSalt
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserSalt($userSalt)
    {
        $this->userSalt = $userSalt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userSalt
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserSalt()
    {
        return $this->userSalt;
    }

    /**
     * Set userToken
     *
     * @param string $userToken
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserToken($userToken)
    {
        $this->userToken = $userToken;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userToken
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUserToken()
    {
        return $this->userToken;
    }

    /**
     * Set userCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userCreated
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserCreated($userCreated)
    {
        $this->userCreated = $userCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserCreated()
    {
        return $this->userCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set userModified
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userModified
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserModified($userModified)
    {
        $this->userModified = $userModified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userModified
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserModified()
    {
        return $this->userModified;
    }

    /**
     * Set userDeleted
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userDeleted
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserDeleted($userDeleted)
    {
        $this->userDeleted = $userDeleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userDeleted
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserDeleted()
    {
        return $this->userDeleted;
    }

    /**
     * Set userLastlogin
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userLastlogin
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserLastlogin($userLastlogin)
    {
        $this->userLastlogin = $userLastlogin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userLastlogin
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserLastlogin()
    {
        return $this->userLastlogin;
    }

    /**
     * Set userConfirmed
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userConfirmed
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserConfirmed($userConfirmed)
    {
        $this->userConfirmed = $userConfirmed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userConfirmed
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserConfirmed()
    {
        return $this->userConfirmed;
    }

    /**
     * Set userLocked
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userLocked
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserLocked($userLocked)
    {
        $this->userLocked = $userLocked;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userLocked
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserLocked()
    {
        return $this->userLocked;
    }

    /**
     * Get userId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles $role
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setRole(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles $role = null)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles 
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Add team
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team
     * @return Users
     */
    public function addTeam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team)
    {
        $this->team[] = $team;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove team
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team
     */
    public function removeTeam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team)
    {
        $this->team->removeElement($team);
    }

    /**
     * Get team
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getTeam()
    {
        return $this->team;
    }

    /**
     * Add competition
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition
     * @return Users
     */
    public function addCompetition(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition)
    {
        $this->competition[] = $competition;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove competition
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition
     */
    public function removeCompetition(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition)
    {
        $this->competition->removeElement($competition);
    }

    /**
     * Get competition
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCompetition()
    {
        return $this->competition;
    }

    private $player;

    /**
     * Get player
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players
     */
    public function getPlayer() {
        return $this->player;
    }
    /**
     * Set player
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players $player
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setPlayer(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players $player){
        $this->player = $player;
    }
}
```

And my Players Entity Class:

```
class Players
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $playerName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_licensenumber", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $playerLicensenumber;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_position", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $playerPosition;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_birthyear", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $playerBirthyear;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="player_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $playerId;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="myteam_id", referencedColumnName="myteam_id")
     * })
     */
    private $myteam;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="team_id")
     * })
     */
    private $team;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;



    /**
     * Set playerName
     *
     * @param string $playerName
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerName($playerName)
    {
        $this->playerName = $playerName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlayerName()
    {
        return $this->playerName;
    }

    /**
     * Set playerLicensenumber
     *
     * @param string $playerLicensenumber
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerLicensenumber($playerLicensenumber)
    {
        $this->playerLicensenumber = $playerLicensenumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerLicensenumber
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlayerLicensenumber()
    {
        return $this->playerLicensenumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set playerPosition
     *
     * @param string $playerPosition
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerPosition($playerPosition)
    {
        $this->playerPosition = $playerPosition;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerPosition
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlayerPosition()
    {
        return $this->playerPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Set playerBirthyear
     *
     * @param \DateTime $playerBirthyear
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setPlayerBirthyear($playerBirthyear)
    {
        $this->playerBirthyear = $playerBirthyear;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerBirthyear
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getPlayerBirthyear()
    {
        return $this->playerBirthyear;
    }

    /**
     * Get playerId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPlayerId()
    {
        return $this->playerId;
    }

    /**
     * Set myteam
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam $myteam
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setMyteam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam $myteam = null)
    {
        $this->myteam = $myteam;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get myteam
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Myteam 
     */
    public function getMyteam()
    {
        return $this->myteam;
    }

    /**
     * Set team
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setTeam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team = null)
    {
        $this->team = $team;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get team
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams 
     */
    public function getTeam()
    {
        return $this->team;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users $user
     * @return Players
     */
    public function setUser(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

My problem is now when I want to submit I get the following error:

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users::setPlayer() must be an instance of VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players, array given, called in /Applications/mampstack-5.4.20-0/apache2/htdocs/volleyscout/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 360 and defined in /Applications/mampstack-5.4.20-0/apache2/htdocs/volleyscout/src/VolleyScout/VolleyScoutBundle/Entity/Users.php line 609
```

**UPDATE:**

The 609 rule is this:

```
public function setPlayer(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players $player){
    $this->player = $player;
}
```

Rule 359, 360 in PropertyAccessor.php

```
if ($reflClass->hasMethod($setter) && $reflClass->getMethod($setter)->isPublic()) {
        $object->$setter($value);
```

Comment: Added rule to begin post (update)

Comment: Actually, the more important line is line 360 of PropertyAccessor.php.

Comment: Added it to begin post

Comment: What is in `$object`? The error message says it's an array. If this is an array of objects, you need to call `$setter` in a loop.

Comment: To restate Barmar's question, we need to see the code that sets `$value` and see why `$value` is an array instead of a Player object.

Comment: BTW it's "enthusiast" not "enthousiast"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's take this error apart so you can see how to figure out error messages.

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error:
```

This is the type of the error.  You can write an error handler to handle these.

```
Argument 1 passed to VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users::setPlayer() 
must be an instance of VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players,
```

This means that when Users::setPlayer() is called, you have to call it using a Player object in the argument.

```
array given,
```

This means that instead of a Player object, there was an array in the argument.

```
called in /Applications/mampstack-5.4.20-0/apache2/htdocs/volleyscout/vendor
/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php 
on line 360
```

This tells you where the problem is:  line 360 of PropertyAccessor.php.

```
and defined in /Applications/mampstack-5.4.20-0/apache2/htdocs/volleyscout
/src/VolleyScout/VolleyScoutBundle/Entity/Users.php line 609
```

This tells you what line of the class Users is involved.

So, all you have to do is change that array on line 360 to a Player object.  Then you can move on to the next error.

EDIT:

Because line 360 is being called from somewhere else, you'll have to trace backwards to whatever was calling line 360.  In this case, it's this line that's giving you an issue:

```
$object->$setter($value);
```

The `$value` is supposed to be a Player object, not an array.  Where is `$value` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem and it drove me nuts.

Once I correctly added this method in the class `PlayerType` extends Abstract Type:

```
/**
* @param OptionsResolver $resolver
*/
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Player'
    ));
}
```

It would know that the array should be casted to the right class. And it worked.