# Symfony2 counting in twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is it really not possible to do simple math in twig or am I missing something? If I am displaying items with a loop and I want to sum the items prices what can I do?

```
  {% for item in product %}
                    <tr>

                      <td> <img width="60" src="{{ asset('bundles/mpFrontend/assets/products/4.jpg') }}" alt=""/></td>

                      <td>{{ item.model }}</td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="input-append"><input class="span1" style="max-width:34px" placeholder="1" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16" type="text">
                        <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-minus"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><a href="{{ path('cart_remove', {'id': key}) }}"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></button>
                        </div>
                      </td>

                      <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
                      <td>{{ item.discount }}</td>
                      <td>{{ item.value }}</td>
                      <td>{{ item.pc }}</td>
                    </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td colspan="6" align="right">Total Price:    </td>
                  <td>{{ item.price|something }}</td>  /// count here
                </tr>

                    {% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE**

My extension class:

```
<?php
// src/Mp/ShopBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace Mp\ShopBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'getTotalPrice'  => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getTotalPrice'));
    }

    public function getTotalPrice(Items $items)
    {
        $total = 0;
        foreach($items as $item){
            $total += $item->getPrice();
        }
        return $total;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

Service:

```
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: Mp\ShopBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        public: false
        tags:
           - { name: twig.extension }
```

When i use {{getTotalPrice(product)}} I am getting an error at that line:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Mp\ShopBundle\Twig\AppExtension::getTotalPrice() must be an instance of Mp\ShopBundle\Twig\Items, none given, called in C:\wamp\www\Digidis\tree\app\cache\dev\twig\b4\5d\b2cbf04f86aeef591812f9721d41a678d3fc5dbbd3aae638883d71c26af0.php on line 177 and defined") in MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig at line 94.

Comment: I suggest you use javascript or jquery to count

Comment: So you really cant do simple math with twig? Just to sum you have to write javascript? Man thats a bummer.

Answer (score 3):

Short snippet to make a sum in Twig :

```
{% set total = 0 %}
{% for product in products %}
    {% set total = total + product.getPrice() %}
{% endfor %}
Total: {{ total }}EUR
```

Answer (score 0):

Dominykas55,

Even though you can do computation in Twig, it is not its role in first place. Do it from your Controller or a Service, or use a Twig function instead.

However, if Twig is required for you, what about this:

```
{% set total = 0 %}
{% for item in product %}
    {% set total = total + total.price %}
{% endfor %}
{{ total }}
```

Each iteration would know about the total, and could you easily display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write you own method for it. Take a look at the documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

All you need is a simple method like this:

```
class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * Returns a list of functions to add to the existing list.
     *
     * @return array An array of functions
     */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'getTotalPrice'  => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getTotalPrice'));
    }

    public function getTotalPrice(Items $items)
    {
        $total = 0;
        foreach($items as $item){
            $total += $item->getPrice();
        }
        return $total;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

and then use it in the template like thsi:

```
{{ getTotalPrice(product) }}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why the getName part is needed for?

Comment: I am not sure what Twig is using it for but since it is part of the `Twig_ExtensionInterface` interface you have to implement this method. As far as I can tell it is used to format exception messages and in profilers.

Comment: Ok, I did everything with your example, and added the service in services.yml like in the documentation, however im getting an error that getTotalPrice does not exist?

Comment: Forgot to add a method that defines the function in Twig. Take a look at the edited answer.

Comment: I am still getting problems. Can you check my edited question please?

Comment: It has been long since I used Twig ;) Try this one `{{ product|getTotalPrice }}` and change the `Item` class to be the one you need there.

Comment: Now it says that the filter getTotalPrice does not exist. I think the getTotalPrice(product) is correct but there is a problem with the code, because im getting an array instead of a value? At least thats what im understanding from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052309/catchable-fatal-error-argument-1-passed-to-must-be-an-instance-of-arra.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76140/discussion-between-awons-and-dominykas55).